# javascript check for a special character at the end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am getting value from a text field. I want to show an alert message if a special character, say % doesn't appear at the end of entered input.

Usecases:

1. ab%C - show alert
2. %abc- show alert
3. a%bc- show alert
4. abc%- ok

The regex i came up so far is this.

```
var txtVal = document.getElementById("sometextField").value;

if (!/^[%]/.test(txtVal))
   alert("% only allowed at the end.");
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: What if `%` is not present in the string?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev. The string wont have it. It's user entered value which will contain the %, meaning user will enter it abcde%f etc.

Comment: are you saying that we can assume that '%' always exists in the string, and we should check if it's the last symbol or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for a regex. indexOf will find the first occurrence of a character, so just check it it's at the end:

```
if(str.indexOf('%') != str.length -1) {
  // alert something
}
```

2020 edit, use [string.endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (/%(?!$)/.test(txtVal))
  alert("% only allowed at the end.");
```

or to make it more readable by not using a `RegExp`:

```
var pct = txtVal.indexOf('%');
if (0 <= pct && pct < txtVal.length - 1) {
  alert("% only allowed at the end.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help, the regex one seems to be work but not the 2nd one.  http://jsfiddle.net/ZHpDN/2/

Comment: @Nomad, That was dumb of me.  Fixed the 2nd.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex to check for this at all.

```
var foo = "abcd%ef";
var lastchar = foo[foo.length - 1];
if (lastchar != '%') {
    alert("hello");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cwu4S/

Comment: thanks for your answer, but your answer doesn't seem to be work. http://jsfiddle.net/4tzmR/1/

Comment: I had two syntax errors in that example. There was an extra closing parenthesis and a missing semicolon. http://jsfiddle.net/4tzmR/3/

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
if (txtVal[txtVal.length-1]=='%') {
    alert("It's there");
}
else {
    alert("It's not there");
}
```